# Can you use Snowpark to run queries in parallel?

Tags: python, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I've got a table of queries that create objects like views, sequences, file_formats etc. I got the DDL statements for the objects and inserted them into the table. So the table only has one column called DDL and each entry is a 'create or replace object' statement etc. I want to use Snowpark to query this table and execute these statements to create the objects and I know you can use a cursor and a for loop but I wanted something more efficient and I don't want them to create one by one waiting for the previous one to finish, I want the statements in the table to **execute asynchronously** so they run on their own without having to wait for other objects to create.

Is there a way to do this in Snowpark, via procedure or a function or something? I'm not too experienced with Snowpark and I've read a lot of things online and looked at videos but I keep getting errors with formatting or just using wrong functions etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The secret to run queries asynchronously with Snowpark Python is `.collect_nowait()`.

For example, this will take no time to enqueue:

```sql
job1 = session.sql('SELECT COUNT(seq4()) FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(TIMELIMIT => 4)) v').collect_nowait()
job2 = session.sql('SELECT COUNT(seq4()) FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(TIMELIMIT => 3)) v').collect_nowait()
job3 = session.sql('SELECT COUNT(seq4()) FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(TIMELIMIT => 2)) v').collect_nowait()
job4 = session.sql('SELECT COUNT(seq4()) FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(TIMELIMIT => 1)) v').collect_nowait()
```

As these queries will be executed asynchronously, the results will take less than the linear 4+3+2+1=9 seconds to run.

[image]

A current limitation: `collect_nowait()` will not work if you call it from within a stored procedure.

Comment: Ah, ok thank you! I'm trying to do a for loop through a table of queries, I set the table in a variable called dataframe using `dataframe = session.table(tableName).filter(col("DDL").isNotNull())` then do the for loop `for row in dataframe` then `query = row["DDL"]` which is the column name I want then  `job = session.sql(query).collect_nowait()` then `print(job.result())` but its not working? Am I missing something in the syntax here?

Comment: Will collect_nowait() work if you call it from a task instead of a stored procedure?